# Deploy ChangeSet but "Added Entity" Errors?

Tags: administration, deployment, change-set

This is very strange to me, as I cannot Google any help on it at all.  It appears that this deployment to our "Full" sandbox went fine despite the "errors" listed where it seems to have ADDED "support" for the Approval Process related items shown.

**Added entity errors**

[image]

Should I be concerned?  I haven't tried it in Production yet - someone is testing it in Full prior to that step.

I went back to the original sandbox, and found nothing else to add to the ChangeSet, manually or otherwise.  This literally **one custom object, one approval process and one workflow,** with their related components, *that's it.*

Thanks!

Comment: Are you deploying the metadata for the Incentive Approval Queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just a warning and perhaps a Salesforce bug. 
It looks like your objects have a list view which is attached to a queue and the queue is linked to your object.

But do your diligence of verifying functionality around the queues and your approval process after the deployment. The deployment to production should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across this issue and managed to resolve it. Within the destination org, I manually created the Object I needed to deploy. However, I only needed to create the base object (none of the fields, queues, etc.) and after that point, the set would deploy. In some cases, this may be easier than a multi-deploy strategy?